# Programatically add multiples ImageView to LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem with my application. I'm trying to generate multiple imageview inside of my linearlayout. Images must be created by my for loop (I get values from a JSONArray).
I've no error but nothings is showing on my device. I can't figure out where's my mystake.

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/layout_netdetails"
    tools:context="ch.gaspardrosay.testapp.NetStatusDetails">

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_net_status_details);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_netdetails);
        iIdStatus = getIntent().getExtras().getString("netdata_suivi");

        try{
            JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(iIdStatus);

            for(int i = 0; i < jsArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject tempJson = jsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Traitement
                String sStatus = (String)tempJson.get("status_suivi");
                String sSuivi = (String)tempJson.get("suivi");

                int iNoStatus = Integer.parseInt(sStatus);
                switch(iNoStatus){
                    case 1:
                        sStatus = "red.png";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sStatus = "orange.png";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sStatus = "green.png";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        sStatus = "blue.png";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        sStatus = "green-orange.png";
                        break;
                }

                Log.i("Status image", sStatus );


                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(NetStatusDetails.this);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(20,20);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);

                imageView.setBackgroundResource(ITToolsMainActivity.GET_RESOURCES.getIdentifier(sStatus, "drawable", ITToolsMainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME));

                layout.addView(imageView);
            }




        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help !

**Edit**

I've tried Hierarchyviewer as it as been suggested. Can't get any results, here's what I get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: tried hierarchyviewer?

Comment: No, have you some examples?

Comment: yes,  go to <sdk>/tools and run hierarchyviewer

Comment: I tried but I didn't get anything... I've added screens to my questions

Comment: ok so instead of imageView.setBackgroundResource try for a while imageView.setBackgroundColor, do you see anything?

Comment: I didn't thought to try it, shame on me... It's showing the background color. But I use the same ressource IDs in another activity and it's showing well !

Comment: what you mean? is the prob solved?

Comment: No not solved but it seems to be the resource that aren't OK

Comment: so try Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resId) and log the drawable

Comment: or just log what ITToolsMainActivity.GET_RESOURCES.getIdentifier returns

Comment: When trying to log it I get an error:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ch.gaspardrosay.testapp/ch.gaspardrosay.testapp.NetStatusDetails}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Comment: so you have Resource ID #0x0, check ITToolsMainActivity.GET_RESOURCES.getIdentifier why...

Comment: I made a mistake when trying to log, I corrected it and seen id = 0, I realized then that I added the ".png" at each resource name...

Comment: great,  and check why hierarchyviewer is not working,  its a useful  testing app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found my error... Everything works fine, I just added the ".png" at each resource name before fetching them.
Removed them and now it works fine.